# How to pipe on require?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, pipe, require

I am trying to read from a `json` file and pipe.

```
return of(
    require(`../../../assets/mydata.json`).pipe(
      map((listItems: ListItem[]) => {
        return { listItems: listItems };
      })
    )
  );
```

But I am getting this error

> ERROR TypeError: **webpack_require**(...).pipe is not a function

Is this possible? Or is there an alternative?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are trying to do. Is this in node or in the browser? If in the browser, you can use `import('your-file.json').then(json => ...);`. If in node, require statements are blocking: `const json = require('your-file.json'); console.log(json);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move a parenthesis:

```js
return of(require(`../../../assets/mydata.json`))
  .pipe(
    map((listItems: ListItem[]) => {
      return { listItems: listItems };
    })
  );
```